# How to re-replicate documents after they have been purged in remote database

Tags: couchdb

I have an application where the documents available in a remote database are a subset of documents available on the server.  When the subset required by the user changes, documents that are no longer needed in the remote database are purged (yes, purged, not deleted) and new documents replicated.  If the subset required by the user was changed to include documents that have been previously purged, I can't find a way to make the purged documents replicate again to reinstate them on the client.

A simple scenario to consider is:

1. Create two databases, A and B
2. Create a document "D" in A
3. Replicate database A to B
4. In B, purge D
5. Replicate A to B again and notice that D is not replicated

I've tried compacting B, to no avail.  I can understand that with continuous replication, D will not be sent again because it has not changed.  But I can't get D to be re-replicated using one-time replication either.  How can I make a replication copy D from A to B once CouchDB is in this state?

I'm using CouchDB 2.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CouchDB stores a local [replication log](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/replication/protocol.html#retrieve-replication-logs-from-source-and-target) on each node, when replication is done.

It's probably fetching this log, and picking up where it left off, thus ignoring changes that happened before the last replication (such as creating documents which are now purged).

I can think of two solutions to this:

1. Manually delete these replication logs, by looking for `_local/` documents, and deleting them.
2. Change, even slightly, the replication parameters, so that CouchDB generates a new [replication ID](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/replication/protocol.html#generate-replication-id) for the sake of logging. One way to do this would be to add a filter function (it could be a filter function that filters nothing).

Comment: I can confirm that both deleting the reflog and changing the replication so that the replication ID changes allows the purged documents to be re-replicated.

For continuous replication, deleting the reflog made it re-replicate the purged document after the replication was restarted.  I restarted CouchDB to force the replication to be restarted, but there is surely a better way to achieve that.

Now the question is, how does one generate the replication ID for a given replication?  I don't think that there is an API call for that...

Comment: You don't have any (direct) control over the replication ID. It's generated automatically by CouchDB.

Comment: The better way is not to purge documents. Purging should not be used in normal database operation, use deletion if you need replication to continue working. Otherwise, the described solution is your best option.

Comment: Deletion is absolutely not acceptable for managing a replicated subset as there is then no way that Couch will re-replicate a document that has been marked deleted locally.  The semantic of delete should remain as a delete.  Purge pertains to storage - as the documentation says, "It will not be available through _all_docs or _changes endpoints, as though this document never existed."  If it's "as though this document never existed" then re-replication should be straightforward.  Personally, I think the right fix is for the replication log to be removed when the replication document is deleted.

Comment: To follow up, it is sufficient to delete the replication log from either the source or destination database involved in the replication.  This is one reason why deleting the target database allows replication to start from the beginning again.