# Using multiple PouchDB instances to share data between multiple CouchDB nodes

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, synchronization, couchdb, pouchdb

For a use case, in which internet and traditional WLAN networking are not possible, I'm trying to share data between nodes by using multiple smartphones. I want to do this by using the synchronization functionalities of PouchDB and CouchDB. The nodes (raspberry pi's) generate unique data and store it in their CouchDB database. The smartphones uses an Angular/Ionic 4 application which implements PouchDB.

Even though it is not possible to create a WLAN network between nodes, it *is* possible to connect the smartphones to the nodes using WiFi: All nodes create a WiFi hotspot. They all have the same SSID and static IP address. Furthermore, the nodes are all isolated from each other.

**Example Scenario**

At first, the PouchDB of the smartphone is empty. Then, the smartphone connects to node 1's hotspot, which lets them perform a two-way sync. Thus, the smartphone now has the data of node 1 in it's PouchDB. The CouchDB of node 1 does not gain additional data, because the PouchDB of the smartphone was empty.

Next, smartphone 1 connects to node 2 and synchronizes. The smartphone should now have data of node 1 and node 2 in it's PouchDB. The CouchDB of node 2 should now have it's own data *and* data of node 1, because the smartphone had it in it's PouchDB.

**Problem**

For some reason, the smartphone's PouchDB is only 'pulling' data from the nodes, but not 'pushing' data it has of other nodes. So in the example above, the smartphone ends up with data of node 1 and 2, but node 2 only has it's own data. The data of node 1 is not transferred to node 2. I'm not seeing any error messages and I dont really know what the cause of this problem could be.

**Code**

The code I'm using is based on [this](https://www.joshmorony.com/offline-syncing-in-ionic-2-with-pouchdb-couchdb/) blogpost. I'm using a service named 'PouchService' which handles the syncing:

```
export class PouchService {
  data: any;
  db: any;
  remote: any; 

  constructor(public app: ApplicationRef, public http: HttpClient) {
     this.db = new PouchDB("eventory");
     this.remote = "http://192.168.4.1:5984/eventorydb";

  let options = {
    live: true,
    retry: true,
    continuous: true,
    auto_compaction: true,     
};

this.db.sync(this.remote, options);
```

So the smartphone creates a local PouchDB named "eventory" and the remote database is called "eventorydb," which is the same for all nodes to make sure the smartphone can automatically connect to the database. The following code is used to do the synchronization:

```
getProducts() {
if (this.data) {
  return Promise.resolve(this.data);
}

return new Promise(resolve => {
  this.db
    .allDocs({
      include_docs: true
    })
    .then(result => {
      this.data = [];
      let docs = result.rows.map(row => {
        this.data.push(row.doc);
      });

      resolve(this.data);

      this.db
        .changes({ live: true, since: "now", include_docs: true })
        .on("change", change => {              
          this.handleChange(change);
        });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
});
}
```

The changes that are then found are handled by:

```
handleChange(change) {
    let changedDoc = null;
    let changedIndex = null;

    this.data.forEach((doc, index) => {
      if (doc._id === change.id) {
        changedDoc = doc;
        changedIndex = index;
      }
    });

    //A document was deleted
    if (change.deleted) {          
      this.data.splice(changedIndex, 1);
      this.app.tick();
    } else {
      //A document was updated
      if (changedDoc) {            
        this.data[changedIndex] = change.doc;
        this.app.tick();
      }

      //A document was added
      else {    
        this.data.push(change.doc);               
        this.app.tick();
      }
    }
  }
```

If something is unclear, please let me know and I will provide more information !

Comment: The CouchDB replication protocol stores replication snapshots locally, so it can resume later. That snapshot is based (in part) on the IP address/hostname of the remote server. If you're using the same IP address on every node, it's going to confuse that mechanism.

Comment: If you can't use different IP addresses, your best bet is probably to delete that checkpoint before each replication. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59282567/13860) for some details.